# How do I implement a comparator for a map in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have a map in Groovy:

```
['keyOfInterest' : 1, 'otherKey': 2]
```

There is a list containing a number of these maps.  I want to know if a map exists in the list with `keyOfInterest` of a certain value.

If the data types were simple objects, I could use `indexOf()`, but I don't know how to do this with a more complicated type. E.g. (taken from the [docs](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_working_with_collections))

```
assert ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c'].indexOf('z') == -1 // 'z' is not in the list
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
def mapA = ['keyOfInterest' : 1, 'otherKey': 2]
def mapB = ['keyOfInterest' : 3, 'otherKey': 2]
def searchMap = ['keyOfInterest' : 1, 'otherKey': 5]
def list = [mapA, mapB]

assert list.indexOf(searchMap) == 0  // keyOfInterest == 1 for both mapA and searchMap
```

Is there a way to do this with more complicated objects, such as a map, easily?

Answer (score 1):

While @dmahapatro is correct, and you can use `find()` to find the map in the list of maps that has the matching index... that's not what you asked for.  So I'll show how you can get either the index of that entry in the list, or just whether a map with matching keyOfInterest exists.

```
def mapA = ['keyOfInterest' : 1, 'otherKey': 2]
def mapB = ['keyOfInterest' : 3, 'otherKey': 2]
def searchMap = ['keyOfInterest':1, 'otherKey': 55 ]
def list = [mapA, mapB]

// findIndexOf() returns the first index of the map that matches in the list, or -1 if none match
  assert  list.findIndexOf { it.keyOfInterest == searchMap.keyOfInterest } == 0 
  assert  list.findIndexOf { it.keyOfInterest == 33 } == -1 

// any() returns a boolean OR of all the closure results for each entry in the list.
   assert list.any { it.keyOfInterest == searchMap.keyOfInterest } == true 
   assert list.any { it.keyOfInterest == 33 } == false
```

Note that there is no performance penalty for using one over the other as they all stop as soon as one match is found.   `find()` gives you the most information, but if you're actually looking for the index or a boolean result, these others can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest implementation would be to use `find()`. It returns null when criteria is not met in the supplied closure.

```
def mapA = ['keyOfInterest' : 1, 'otherKey': 2]
def mapB = ['keyOfInterest' : 3, 'otherKey': 2]
def list = [mapA, mapB]

assert  list.find { it.keyOfInterest == 1 } == ['keyOfInterest':1, 'otherKey':2]
assert !list.find { it.keyOfInterest == 7 }
```

Comment: While that works, it doesn't find the INDEX as specified in the examples... that's why there's findIndexOf()

Comment: using `indexOf()` (similar to JavaScript) was one of the approach used to find the presence of an element. However, `findIndexOf(groovy.lang.Closure)` takes a closure similar to `find()`. This brings a good point. With Groovy 2.4, `indexed()` transforms the list to create a map where the index of each element becomes the key.